# Zoomable Treemap in Bokeh

Tags: zooming, bokeh, treemap

I was wondering if anyone had any links to work for a zoomable treemap in Bokeh.  Similar to the Mike Bostock example: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/

In particular:  there doesn't seem to be (as yet) a treemap layout in Bokeh, perhaps this would be the first place to start?  Then I would assume that some form of animation would need to be done to flow from one tree hierarchy to the next.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in Bokeh, but you would need to compute the space-packing/rectangle positions manually, there is nothing built in to do this.

Additionally, as of Bokeh `0.13.0`, "smooth animations" is still an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/128), so the transitions would be instantaneous, not "zoomy".

If you'd like to have something considered as a new feature (especially if you can help contribute), the best thing is to make a [GitHub issue to discuss it.](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues)